# With ToList or AsQueryable Calling procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I wonder, if I call procedure with `.ToList()` or `.AsQueryable()` does have same effect in Entity Framework?

Look at this:

```
var query1 = DB.sp_GetConsultants().AsQueryable();
var query2 = DB.sp_GetConsultants().ToList();
```

I knew that `AsQueryable` just creates a query and `ToList` executes it, but when
I looked into SQL Server Profiler and saw that both query1 and query2 executes.

Here is a screenshot to prove it:

[image]

But if I query it directly in tables without calling stored procedure, it looks fine, only `ToList` executes query and not `AsQueryable`:

```
var query1 = DB.Consultants.AsQueryable();
var query2 = DB.Consultants.ToList();
```

Comment: A stored procedure cannot be used as an "queryable", since it's already executed its statement and the data is "materialized". So yes - if you call a stored procedure, it will **always** be executed against SQL Server - using `.AsQueryable()` is pointless - the server will be queried and the data retrieved when you execute the stored procedure.

Comment: @marc_s I am using server side filtering, because of I use stored procedure it dose not make seance to build up where clause strings in C#.  right am I? Can you advice me what to do?

Comment: Well, the point is: *if* you use stored procedure, then you **cannot** make use of the niceties of `IQueryable` - plain and simple. If that's something you *need* or want - then you need to dump your stored procedures and create your queries "ad-hoc" in EF